# Incomplete java.net.URL.openStream() stream

Tags: java, https, io

I’m using `java.net.URL.openStream()` to access a HTTPS resource. The returned stream is incomplete for some URLs: for the example below, it yields a 1,105,724 byte-file whereas the same URL accessed from a browser yields a 5,755,858 byte-file (even when "disabling" `Content-Encoding`).

And it doesn’t even throw an exception.

What am I missing?

```
import static java.nio.file.Files.copy;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    try (final InputStream in = new URL(
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Germany_%28orthographic_projection%29.svg").openStream()) {
      copy(in, Paths.get("germany.svg"));
    }
  }
}
```

## Edit

I’ve tested this code a lot of times (on different networks, but always on JRE 1.8.0_60 / Mac OS X 10.11.4), and sometimes it’s suddenly "starting to work".

However, switching to another of my problematic URLs (e.g. `"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Andorra_in_Europe_%28zoomed%29.svg"`) enables me to reproduce the issue.

Does this mean that it is a server issue? I’ve never seen it on a browser though.

Comment: Hmmm how did you measure that 5,755,858 byte-file? That not what I get when downloading manually the file and checking its size.

Comment: @Tunaki I get the same size as OP when I download it manually from the navigator or from curl

Comment: Works fine for me... Are you sure you are on a stable network?

Comment: @JulienRoyer which version of Java do you use? Because with Java 1.8.0_77, I can reproduce your issue with 1.7, it works as expected

Comment: this getting weird I can't even reproduce anymore even with Java 8

Comment: @NicolasFilotto are you also running Mac OS X?

Comment: @JulienRoyer yes but I tested on a VM hosted on my MBP running Windows 7 and I faced the same issue

Answer (score -2):

It's working fine.

As others have suggested there may be a problem with your network, try connecting to another network.

```
package test;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class TestMain2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Started");

        try (final InputStream in = new URL(
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Germany_%28orthographic_projection%29.svg")
                        .openStream()) {

            Path outputFile = Paths.get("test.svg");

            Files.copy(in, outputFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

            System.out.println("Output file size : " + outputFile.toFile().length());

            System.out.println("Finished");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Started
Output file size : 5755858
Finished
```

Comment: If it is only a network issue, how do you explain that it works through a browser?

Comment: If it works fine, please just vote to close as unreproducible. The answer "it works for me" isn't helpful. And _there may be a problem with your network_ isn't conclusive and just a guess.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Julien hasn't posted code for copy, that's what I included in answer, issue could be there too.

Comment: @JulienRoyer, Check if the code I posted works for you

Comment: _Code for copy_? Do you mean `Files.copy`? That's part of the JDK. It's in his imports just like yours.